# How to check whether two many2many fields are exactly equal or not in odoo9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-website

I have a many2many field "tag_ids" both in models "news.ads" and "blog.post".

I want to get all the records from "blog.post" whose "tag_ids" exactly matches the "tag_ids" in "news.ads".

I tried the following in my controller but it doesn't worked,

```
blog_obj = request.registry['blog.post']

p_id = blog_obj.search(cr, uid, ['&', ['id','=',post_id], ['website_published', '=', True]], context=context)

post = blog_obj.browse(cr, uid, p_id, context=context)


ad_obj = request.registry['news.ads']

banner_ads = ad_obj.search(cr, uid, [('state', '=', 'publish'), ('tag_ids', 'in', [post.tag_ids])], context=context)
```

How do I search such records in odoo9? Any workaround..!!

Answer (score 1):

with the old api, search already returns a list of id's of the matching records, so there is no need to call browse again, you can use the returned list directly in your domain filter

```
blog_obj = request.registry['blog.post']

p_id = blog_obj.search(cr, uid, ['&', ['id','=',post_id], ['website_published', '=', True]], context=context)

# post = blog_obj.browse(cr, uid, p_id, context=context) you don't need this

ad_obj = request.registry['news.ads']

banner_ads = ad_obj.search(cr, uid, [('state', '=', 'publish'), ('tag_ids', 'in', p_id)], context=context)
```

in the new api, which is highly recommended you'll have to go an extra step and extract the id's yourself because search now returns a record set

```
p_id = blog_obj.search(['&', ['id','=',post_id], ['website_published', '=', True]])

p_id = [p.id for p in p_id]
```

Answer (score -1):

Note 1: **DON'T USE OLD API IN ODOO-8 AND ODOO-9**

First phase:

To get all the many2many id list we are using `.ids` it will return list.

Second phase:

Situation: We have two list, and you want to get items from second list, if they are in first list.

```
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> b
[2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 13]
>>> c = [x for x in b if x in a]
>>> c
[2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

Note 2: I'm odoo-8 developer.